# Add json key from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, dictionary

I'm trying to add elements to a JSON from items of an array, but I'm struggling to pass the elements to the JSON.

here is my code:

```js
var j = {
    "Root": {
        "a": "1800,1200,3100",
        "b": "1500,1999,2001",
        "c": "40,60,50",
        "d": "this is not needed",
        "e": "nor this one"
    }
};
var root = j.Root,
    l = root.a.split(",").length,
    hash = ["a", "b", "c"];


for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < hash.length; x++) {
        root['row_' + i] = {
            "a": root.a.split(",")[i],
            "b": root.b.split(",")[i],
            "c": root.c.split(",")[i] // I don't want to do this for each key
        };
    }
}



for (var x = 0; x < hash.length; x++) {
    delete root[hash[x]];
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(j));
```

My code is working, but I'm looking for a proper way to use the elements of my array because I will have more than a,b,c

**PS: not all key will be used**

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) What you have is a JavaScript object.

Comment: Where is the array? What is your expected output?

Comment: @phuzi, thank you for the remark, can you help ?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal the array is the hash, my expected output is correct, but I don't want to explicitly name every element in my loop

Comment: @Jonathan ok I have added a answer

Comment: does the keys reflect the length of the data?

Comment: @NinaScholz no.

Comment: how do you know if the value is not an array if splitted?

Comment: @NinaScholz the only keys that need to be used are the ones that have a "," in their value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` which will give you the keys for the object in `hash` variable. Then it will be dynamic for your code to detect all the possible keys in `Root` object:

```js
var j = {
    "Root": {
        "a": "1800,1200,3100",
        "b": "1500,1999,2001",
        "c": "40,60,50",
        "d": "152,199,21",
        "e": "15,19,200"
    }
};
var root = j.Root,
    l = root.a.split(",").length,
    hash = ["a", "b", "c"];


for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var x = 0; x < hash.length; x++) {
        obj[hash[x]] = root[hash[x]].split(",")[i];
    }
    root['row_' + i] = obj;
}


for (var x = 0; x < hash.length; x++) {
    delete root[hash[x]];
}
console.log(root);
console.log(JSON.stringify(j));
```

Comment: the problem is I will not use all the key of the object, I will only use the ones that can be split

Comment: What do you mean by that @Jonathan

Comment: @Jonathan check now

Comment: @Jonathan check now. It should be fine.

Comment: After making it generic you now have added a list of specific keys to make it non-generic again O.o

Comment: @Andreas The keys are not specific. You see that there is a `hash` variable that says that only the variables in `hash` needs to be changed for the keys

Comment: But you still have to know the keys before one can use your solution. And there's no `Object.keys()` anymore which you're proposing as the solution.

Comment: @Andreas check what the OP asks. He says he only want to have `hash` variables and not all the keys. So, there might be the case that `hash` variable is known with the name of the keys.

Comment: @Jonathan glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the keys and build new properties.

```js
var object = { Root: { a: "1800,1200,3100", b: "1500,1999,2001", c: "40,60,50", d: "this is not needed", e: "nor this one" } },
    reference = object.Root;

Object
    .keys(reference)
    .forEach(k => {
        var values = reference[k].split(',');
        if (values.length === 1) {
            return;
        }
        values.forEach((v, i) => {
            reference['row_' + i] = reference['row_' + i] || {};
            reference['row_' + i][k] = v;
        });        
        delete reference[k];
    });

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get your required result using the following methods

1. [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
2. [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
3. [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
4. [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

**DEMO**

```js
const root = {
    "Root": {
      "a": "1800,1200,3100",
      "b": "1500,1999,2001",
      "c": "40,60,50",
      "d": "this is not needed",
      "e": "nor this one"
    }
  },
  hash = ["a", "b", "c"],
  keys = Object.keys(root.Root);


let result = Object.values(root.Root).reduce((obj, value, index) => {
  if (value.match(',')) {
    value = value.split(',');
    obj[`row_${index}`] = hash.reduce((object, key, index) => {
      object[key] = value[index];
      return object;
    }, {});
  } else {
    obj[keys[index]] = value;
  }
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what happened to d & e ?

Comment: @Jonathan I have included `d` & `e` as well. Please check